# Integrating Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

If I want to integrate Android Wear into my app, do I need to rewrite the whole app for the Wear Device or can the App on the wear device use the SharedPrefs, functions and so on  from the "normal" Device?
Is there a good tutorial for that?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider app for Android Wear device as a separate app (it's inside separate apk bundled in parent apk i.e actual Android app) that communicates with your master Android app on the device. It's run directly on the wearable device and does not have direct access to things like SharedPreferences. Of course you can implement such access using Data Layer API.

I'd recommend you to start from Android Wear official developer guide: https://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
Why didn't Google thought of such a logical step to let me easily use my shared Prefs and functions? 
Sometimes Android feels like Google doesn't finish any of their thoughts.